# Alignment in latex

Tags: align

I am putting my solutions in latex format but I can't write it properly because I can't align (see image). Is there any way that I can align the `u` and `du` to the integrands in the image?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us an example which reproduce your problem. Also, please add to question a image about your problem

Comment: The equation is wrong, the notation is unfortunate, to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos y}{\sin y}\, dy  & = \int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\, dx  \\
\begin{aligned}
 u & = \sin y       \\                    
du & = \cos(y)\, dy
\end{aligned}                   &\qquad \begin{aligned}
                                     u & = \cos x       \\
                                    du & = -\sin(x)\, dx
                                        \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\int\frac{\cos y}{\sin y}\, dy}_{%
           \begin{aligned}
            u & = \sin y       \\
           du & = \cos(y)\, dy
           \end{aligned}}     = \underbrace{\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\, dx}_{%
                                   \begin{aligned}
                                    u & = \cos x       \\
                                   du & = -\sin(x)\, dx
                                       \end{aligned}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what &\qquad does?

Comment: The equation is wrong, the notation is unfortunate, to say the least.

Comment: @rmp, ampersands are anchor of equations. `\qquad` insert space with width of ˙\qquad` before `aligned` in the right side of equations. See added example in my answer.

Comment: @TikZling, please, enlighten us with your answer, where you will show how should be correct notations ...

Comment: The equation is wrong. Do you agree? (The differentials are wrong as well. But since the equation is wrong it does not matter so much it it is in addition unreadable.)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have the substitutions right aligned with the integral on the left and left aligned with the one on the right.

You can use `alignat` in order to make multiple alignment points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\int\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}\, dy  & ={} &&\! \int\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\, dx  \\
\begin{aligned}
 u & = \sin(y) \\
du & = \cos(y)\, dy
\end{aligned}
&&&
\begin{aligned}
 u & = \cos(x) \\
du & = -\sin(x)\, dx
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I won't question the math, which seems just a mockery for a real situation.

Notes.

1. `={}` is needed in order to get correct spacing: no space after the `=` sign would be added by TeX, otherwise.
2. `\!` before `\int` is needed to avoid incorrect spacing: after an odd-numbered `&`, `alignat` adds `{}` (that is responsible for the correct spacing of the relation symbol that usually starts even-numbered columns); in this case it would add a thin space because `\int` follows immediately.